# JQuery: infinite loop because $(document).height() hasn''t been updated

Tags: jquery, height, document

I'm trying to implement an infinite scrolling on my homepage. However the following script will cause and infinite loop because $(document).height() will never change. Can you help me? I understand that this is caused by css but I can't find a solution. I tried both to put the code into $(window).load and $(document).ready but it doesn't work.

```
while( $(document).height() <= $(window).height() ) {
load();//load the data at the bottom of the homepage
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't suppose `load` is asynchronous?

Comment: It uses the jquery function $.get so I suppose that yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jQuery [.scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).

`$(document).height()` `and $(window).height()` will always be fixed and will not change.

However, using `$(window).scrollTop()`, you know how far down the page you have scrolled, so you can then add your window height to work out when you are at the bottom of the page and load you content at that point.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/2tEcA/)

Comment: The matter is that I need to call the load function until all the page will be full of contents. So before loading the page will be empty and there will be no scrolling avaiable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you never give your `load` a chance to complete before checking the `height`.  Javascript is single threaded, so by the fact that your code never completes, the `get` result is never processed.

What you will need to do is call `load` only once and then in the callback for `get`, try again if needed.

Something like this should work:

```
function getMore(){
    if( $(document).height() <= $(window).height() ) {
        load();
    }
}

function load(){
    /* ... */
    $.get(/* ... */, function(){
        // after the first get completes, call getMore again
        getMore();
    });
}
```

You may potentially need to tweak that `if` condition to get it exactly how you want it, but this will fix the issue of the infinite loop.  You will probably want to have a wrapper `div` and compare that height against the `window` height, instead of using `document`.

Comment: Actually it seems not to work because the .height() attributes of my div didn't change after the load. Any other ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: You loaded more stuff into your div and its height didn't change?  How can that be?  Do you have a defined height on your div?

Comment: Sorry you are right: the height changes. However I've still got a problem with the if condition. 
if( $("#id").height() <= + $(window).height() ) {load();
I checked with an alert but it the #id height is always bigger than $(window).height() but I don't understand how it is possible: the #id div is not so big (it doesn't occupy all the screen!). How could it be possible? I saw that $(window).height is alway bery small (between 200 and 400). Thanks      }

Comment: Is this perhaps in an iframe or something?  Would it be possible for you to create a demo?

Comment: Tomorrow I will. However have a normal html page which contains a div element. I simply append some html to that div. Nothing else. But  the $(window).height seems to be very small. It is the browser windows height, isn't it?